# How to capture a swallowed Tab key when using ActiveX, Delphi, and DevExpress?

Tags: delphi, com, devexpress, activex, keyboard-events

This is a very particular issue.  I've got a C# ActiveX control embedded in a Delphi7 form.  The Tab key is being swallowed so tabbing from control to control doesn't work at the bottom most layer.

The Delphi7 layers are (from top to bottom):

1. Delphi form
2. DevExpress tabbed page control (TcxPageControl)
3. Embedded ActiveX

The ActiveX's layers are (from top to bottom):

1. A control that inherits DevExpress's control (XtraUserControl).  This control is the COM visible object that is embedded in the Delphi form.
2. DevExpress panel (PanelControl)
3. DevExpress tab control (XtraTabControl)
4. DevExpress tab page (XtraTabPage)
5. DevExpress Textbox (TextEdit)

Tabbing from textbox to textbox doesn't work. PreviewKeyDown events don't fire from ActiveX's tab page and down. KeyDown event fires on ActiveX's tab control when I TAB, but this event doesn't exist at lower levels.

Tabbing works just fine if I put embed the ActiveX control in a C# form with all the same layers instead of Dephi7.

Delphi7's form has this code in it, which allows tabbing to work in other ActiveX controls I have embedded:

```
keybd_event(VK_TAB, 0, 0, 0);
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

I embed the control in code the same way I have done numerous other times with other ActiveX controls (which all work).

My thought is that there are too many layers and somehow the Tab key is being swallowed by a middle layer.  How would I make tabbing work at the bottom layer?

Comment: In case I've failed to make clear what I'm asking: is the tab key really swallowed, or is it that the focus switches from the activex control to a native VCL control?

Comment: I know that if I'm on a particular tab of the ActiveX tab control, then TAB'ing moves me to the next tab.  I've created a set of OnEnter, OnKeyDown, and OnPreviewKeyDown events.  OnKeyDown is fired when I'm in the bottom layer textbox, but focus doesn't move anywhere.

Comment: Your first sentence suggests that the key message is properly delivered to the activex control, then it looks like an issue with the control itself. If what I suspected had been true, after pressing the tab key while you're on a textbox, you wouldn't be able to write on that box any more (focus should have been switched to elsewhere).

Comment: Found this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187988) that might explain the problem.  I'm going to test it out and will let you.

Comment: it is what I've been querying about. If it were true, the hosting application, VCL, would focus a control of its own.